# solving for expected value poisson regression

Tags: r, logging, regression, glm, poisson

I have the number of tracks running in the brain between each pair of brain regions labelled Sij.  I also have the distance of the tracks between each pair of regions labelled gij.
i and j represent each brain region.

So for instance this if file:

```
Sij    gij
331     15.2
428     11.1
797     45
313     54
142     12
```

I'm trying to adjust the bias for values of gij that fall below 12 distance with a poisson regression model.

What I'm trying to do is solve to get alpha0 and alpha1 given this poisson model with log link function:

```
log(μ(Sij|gij))=α0+α1gij
```

But the issue here is that I wasn't sure how to find this value: μ(Sij|gij), which is equivalently called the expected value E(x).

I was thinking of doing this is r code:

```
summary(m1 <- glm(Sij$file ~ gij$file, family=poisson(link=log), data=p))
```

but what I'm understanding is that from this I'll get the alpha0 and alpha1 but I'm not sure how to get the expected value

Comment: Sounds like you needs stats help rather than programming help. You should consult the statisticians over at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 0):

there is a command, for expected value, which is the weighted mean:

```
weighted.mean(Sij, gij)
```